# table top segmentation from kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, openni-kinect, tabletop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Does anyone know how to best achieve table top object segmentation from kinect sensor? is there any module/tutorial you can recommend me to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10338/table-top-segmentation-from-kinect/) by [Dina Abdel-Hamid](https://answers.ros.org/users/725/dina-abdel-hamid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the [openni_kinect package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) to set up your Kinect. You should be able to view the published point cloud topic in RViz.

Then, you can go through the [pcl tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials) and [pcl_ros tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials). Tutorial 6 from the pcl_ros tutorials (SACSegmentationFromNormals planar segmentation) should do exactly what you need.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the [tabletop_object_detector](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_detector) in my manipulation stack branch.

I wrote an (incomplete) [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sr_hand/Tutorials/Running%20the%20sr_object_manipulation%20stack%20%5BUNSTABLE%5D) explaining what's going on.

You can check the code from here:
`lp:~ugocupcic/sr-ros-interface/manipulation`

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on 2015-12-13**:
I went through tutorial link. I wish to implement this. Will it work in ROS Indigo (ubuntu 14.04)? Also I am unable to access the code.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2016-01-05**:
the tutorial in my answer is really old. You should probably take a look at this: http://wg-perception.github.io/tabletop

**Comment by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on 2016-01-25**:
thanks Ugo, is your code open source. Could I have a look at it. This link which you have given above does not work for me. Thanks again for your time

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2016-01-26**:
That is strange, the link to the [wiki above](http://wg-perception.github.io/tabletop/) works for me. It's not a link to the code directly though, it's a wiki. Let me know if you can access it?

**Comment by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on 2016-01-26**:
Thanks Ugo the wiki link works for me. I thought you implemented it, so wanted to see the code, however, l have been going through the wiki and has been very comprehensive. Thanks again